# Why docker close the tcp connection immediately?

Tags: docker, telnet, netcat, busybox

I use this command to test the net connectivity in the terminal:

```
docker run --rm --name test -it -p 9999:9999 busybox nc -l 0.0.0.0:9999
```

and in another terminal

```
$ telnet localhost 9999
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

seemed it connected by closed immediately, I can not input anything.

it's working fine when I try localy

```
nc -l 0.0.0.0:9999
```

and

```
telnet localhost 9999
```

Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6
Ubuntu VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 total different style `netcat`. The `nc` in container is not the same series with your host, so host pass, container solution fail.

I guess your host `nc` is not traditional one, something like follows:

```
# nc
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.
usage: nc [-46bCDdhjklnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
      [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-q seconds] [-s source]
      [-T toskeyword] [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]
```

You container `nc` is a different version, it has a total different command syntax:

```
# docker run --rm --name test -it -p 9999:9999 busybox /bin/sh
/ # nc
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2018-10-01 22:37:18 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

        -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
        -l      Listen mode, for inbound connects
        -lk     With -e, provides persistent server
        -p PORT Local port
        -s ADDR Local address
        -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
        -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
        -n      Don't do DNS resolution
        -u      UDP mode
        -v      Verbose
        -o FILE Hex dump traffic
        -z      Zero-I/O mode (scanning)
```

If you use `netstat` in container, you will find `9999` port was not open with your command, as a result, your client quit immediately.

So, you need to change your command to follows:

```
docker run --rm --name test -it -p 9999:9999 busybox nc -l -p 9999
```